# reading output of ptx

Tags: python, serial-port, virtual

i open a virtual serial port (pair) using the python code i found on here:

```
import os, pty, serial, time

master, slave = pty.openpty()
s_name = os.ttyname(slave)
print "slave name: " + s_name
print "master name:" + os.ttyname(master)

ser = serial.Serial(s_name)

while( 1) :
        ser.write('Your text\n')
        ser.flush()
        time.sleep(5)
```

output:

```
slave name: /dev/pts/5
master name:/dev/ptmx
```

but when i try to see the output using:

> cat /dev/ptmx

nothing comes out.

i added the flush and carriage return in case it needs. (i also looked at `/dev/pts/5` but it returns right away without any output

am i missing anything ?

**note**: i noticed that the output of 
    ser.write('Your text\n')
is None ? , but it does not throw an exception